# Custom XBL scrollbar(not only colors!) in browser window and in HTML page in tabs

Tags: css, firefox-addon, xul

I want custom XBL scrollbar: Add event `mousedown` to `thumb`, `slider` and my `duppa` tag. Add styles to this elements. For all `scrollbar`s in browser window and for all `scrollbar`s in all tabs pages.

I register StyleSheet.

It working in browser window but not working in html page in tabs:
`-moz-binding` working in browser window.
`-moz-binding` not working for html page in tabs.
Other styles working in browser window and in HTML page in tabs.

What to do to it work on HTML page in tabs?

```
var self = require('sdk/self');
const {Cc, Ci, Cu} = require("chrome");
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');
var sss = Cc['@mozilla.org/content/style-sheet-service;1'].getService(Ci.nsIStyleSheetService);
var cssUri = Services.io.newURI(self.data.url('scroll-bar.css'), null, null);

sss.loadAndRegisterSheet(cssUri, sss.AGENT_SHEET);
```

data/scroll-bar.css(for example):

```
scrollbar {
-moz-appearance: none !important;
border: none !important;
-moz-binding: url("resource://adrr/data/scrollbar.xml#scrollbar");
}
duppa {
background: green;
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
}
```

data/scrollbar.xml (for example):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public
- License, v. 2.0. If a copy of the MPL was not distributed with this
- file, You can obtain one at http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/. -->
<bindings id="scrollbarBindings" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/xbl" xmlns:xul="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul" xmlns:xbl="http://www.mozilla.org/xbl">

<binding id="thumb" extends="xul:button"/>

<binding id="scrollbar-base" bindToUntrustedContent="true">
<handlers>
<handler event="contextmenu" preventdefault="true" action="event.stopPropagation();"/>
<handler event="click" preventdefault="true" action="event.stopPropagation();"/>
<handler event="dblclick" action="event.stopPropagation();"/>
<handler event="command" action="event.stopPropagation();"/>
</handlers>
</binding>

<binding id="scrollbar" clickthrough22="dupa" bindToUntrustedContent="true" extends="resource://cvanux-at-lukaszpolowczyk/data/scrollbar.xml#scrollbar-base">
<content clickthrough="always">
<xul:duppa sbattr="scrollbar-up-bottoxm" type="decrement" xbl:inherits="curpos,maxpos,disabled,sborient=orient"/>
<xul:scrollbarbutton sbattr="scrollbar-up-top" type="decrement" xbl:inherits="curpos,maxpos,disabled,sborient=orient"/>
<xul:scrollbarbutton sbattr="scrollbar-down-top" type="increment" xbl:inherits="curpos,maxpos,disabled,sborient=orient"/>
<xul:slider flex="1" xbl:inherits="disabled,curpos,maxpos,pageincrement,increment,orient,sborient=orient">
<xul:thumb sbattr="scrollbar-thumb" xbl:inherits="orient,sborient=orient,collapsed=disabled" align="center" pack="center"/>
</xul:slider>
<xul:scrollbarbutton sbattr="scrollbar-up-bottom" type="decrement" xbl:inherits="curpos,maxpos,disabled,sborient=orient"/>
<xul:scrollbarbutton sbattr="scrollbar-down-bottom" type="increment" xbl:inherits="curpos,maxpos,disabled,sborient=orient"/>
</content>
</binding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: You registered to hit, `scrollbar { -moz-binding:.... }` which is the right way? So whats the issue? Is your xbl is not working?

Comment: It working for `browser window`, `sidebar`, `devtools`. Not workig for html pages in tabs. But the same `scrollbar { -moz-appearance: none !important;}` working in pages.  Only moz-binding is problem. Please, help.
http://oi58.tinypic.com/2euhgr8.jpg

Comment: Interesting, try changing ` sss.AGENT_SHEET` to ` sss.AUTHOR_SHEET`

Comment: With `AUTHOR_SHEET` styles is not working at all except in the side panel.

Comment: Interesting, did you try `USER_SHEET`? Also try setting `!important` on your binding.

Comment: Yes. With you too, so work? You did something similar?

Comment: Hm very interesting I cant get it to work either. Nuts man